# Changing resolution on Ubuntu 18.04 with Nvidia

Tags: nvidia, display, 18.04, display-resolution

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and that resolution was locked at 600x480 or something like that. I found a way to increase it to 1024x768, but it seems that is the max it will go.

I changed the GFXMode to do that.

Trying to make a custom resolution from xrandr doesn't work, because in place of VGA-O, it says default for me.

I'm not sure what to do anymore. Nvidia driver is 390.

```
~$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2881 x 1280, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 connected 1600x1280+1281+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
```

Comment: Hi, can you log-on with xorg instead of Wayland and see if it can give you option to select your resolution?

Comment: @PRATAP Wayland does not work with proprietary Nvidia drivers, and Xorg is the default in 18.04.

Comment: As you state, you are connected via VGA cable. This type of connection requires manual configuration. However, with proprietary NVidia drivers as you've stated you're using, `xrandr` will not work. You must use the NVidia config tool instead to manage such settings.

Comment: Is yours desktop or laptop? I am using Toshiba laptop and it has the same nvidea drivers you mentioned. I have checked with xorg and Wayland. It is working.

Comment: Sorry.. You are rite.. When I selected nvidea drivers and restarted the system.. The cog wheel disappeared.. After logging in I reverted to X.Org X server and restarted.. Now cog wheel appeared.

Comment: @dobey What nvidia tool would that be?

Comment: @UbunGiraffeTale the one installed along with the proprietary drivers. Something like `nvidia-settings` IIRC.